# Convert every 2nd & 3rd row into a column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a long list which of a persons name, job title and company. The problem is it's in one long list e.g.

```
Joe Smith
Director
Google
Sam Jones
Marketer
Facebook
Etc
```

Which makes it very difficult to read. Can I convert this so I end up with a table with first name, job title and company all on separate columns?

Comment: Is this (by that I mean `Joe Smith Director Google Sam Jones Marketer Facebook`) all written in one single cell? You would need a way to tell whether something is a name, job title or company name. A simple `split()` on space won't do as a name, job title or company name could itself consist of many words

Comment: I think it would be better if you could provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the input data and the desired output so that we get a better understanding of what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=QUERY({QUERY(A1:A20, "skipping 3", ), 
        QUERY(A2:A21, "skipping 3", ), 
        QUERY(A3:A22, "skipping 3", )}, "where Col1 is not null")
```

[image]